# Is it better to send AJAX calls to a PHP script? Or use PHP in the page?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if I should let one php script do all of the sqli interactions and access the information with AJAX calls, or if I should handle those interactions as needed on the same page. Are there any security issues with either. What is best practice?

Comment: I would imagine it varies according to the use case.

Comment: Lets say for authentication of a user.

Comment: That's a really bad use case for SPAs - there are additional considerations here (notably HTTPONLY flags on cookies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite subjective, as there is a fair bit of personal preference. Without knowing exactly what is on the page, and how much time you you want to spend working on it, and you skill level, we can't say for sure which is best.

There are some advantages, and disadvantages

If you render everything in the page, then the page itself will be slower to initially load in the browser, so if initial load time is important to you, use ajax requests.

If you are writing basic admin pages, CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) records, and it is only used for a handful of users, maybe you can save time building them by using full page requests.

Personally I find it faster to write/debug full pages rendered in php, just because I am not also writing js/jquery/react or whatever flavour of client side scripting you are working with.

With ajax, you tend to end up doing validation both on the client side, and the server side, as you can never trust the data sent to your sever, the end user can easily work around js validation.

From an end user perspective, I find that ajax requests provide a nicer experience. The user gets to see a page load fast, with some spinners (so you know something is happening), then parts of the page load, think of the likes of facebook, scroll down and you have infinite scrolling, the next lot of stories load and append to the page, without reloading the whole lot.

Security wise, full page requests and ajax requests are generally as secure as each other, most rely on cookies for authentication, and cookies work equally for both methods.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answer from @bumperbox.....

With the Ajax model where transitions are via Javascript changing the content on the page (commonly referred to as a Single Page Application or SPA) rather than a refresh of the base HTML, there is a significant risk of memory leaks. Diagnosing behaviour remotely or even just collecting analytics is a PITA.

Conversely it's rare to see a web page that doesn't contain Javascript and CSS - loading and processing these is a major performance bottleneck. If they are only loaded once (i.e. in a SPA) then that bottleneck is eliminated on subsequent pseudo-navigation events.

Just to confuse things even more - [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) combines the benefits of both approaches while eliminating some of the disadvantages.